# Docusign: PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED when using docusign.esign.dll 5.0.0

Tags: docusignapi

[image]

When I am using same `development` keys and `private rsa key` in sample `app` provided by `docusign` then that is working. But when using same keys in my application is shows below error while creating envelope.

Sample app has `docusign.esign.dll` 4.1.1 and in my case its `docusign.esign.dll` 5.0.0.

Anything I am missing while calling `CreateEnvelope` or is there any configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the code you used to obtain accessToken, but you should ensure that you provided the correct information and the same environment (account-d vs. account.docusign.com).

Also, you create a new Configuration() object called config, but then use _configuration in the code I can use. This is a bit odd. I wonder if you set the BaseUrl correctly for the _configuration object you did use.

Also, you need to pass the config object when to the API so that it is used.

Comment: Actually `_configuration` object has properties like access token, baseuri which get set while retrieving `access token` and `userinfo`. Here actual issue was, I was not passing `config` object to `ApiClient`.